# Spark Streaming with Elasticsearch connector throws JVM_Bind error

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using **Spark 2.1.1** in Java and *elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11* (version 5.3.2) in order to write data in *Elasticsearch*.I create *JavaStreamingContext* which I then set to await termination, so the application should always retrieve new data.

After I read the stream, I split it into RDDs and for each one I apply SQL aggregations and then write it to Elasticsearch as follows:

```
        recordStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                /*
                 * Create RDD from JSON
                 */
                Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(rdd.rdd());
                df.createOrReplaceTempView("data");
                df.cache();
                /*
                 * Apply the aggregations
                 */
                Dataset aggregators = spark.sql(ORDER_TYPE_DB);
                JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(aggregators.toDF(), "order_analytics/record");
                aggregators = spark.sql(ORDER_CUSTOMER_DB);
                JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(aggregators.toDF(), "customer_analytics/record");
            }
        });
```

This works fine the first time data is read and inserted to *Elasticsearch*, but when more data are retrieved by the stream, I get the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopTransportException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:461)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:429)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:627)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:644)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:433)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.commonshttp.CommonsHttpTransport.execute(CommonsHttpTransport.java:478)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:112)
    ... 16 more
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Spark uses default configuration and is instantiated in Java as

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(topic).setMaster("local");
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(2));
```

Elasticsearch is configured via *Docker compose* with the following environment parameters:

```
    - cluster.name=cp-es-cluster
    - node.name=cloud1
    - http.cors.enabled=true
    - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
    - network.host=0.0.0.0
    - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=${ENV_IP}
    - network.publish_host=${ENV_IP}
    - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
```

Comment: Can you share elastic search yaml file and spark config file?

Comment: I added this information in the problem description

Comment: Can you please kill the java process running behind and restart the spark-submit job?

Comment: I have tried this but every time the same thing happens: the first data insertion is completed successfully but every following one fails. I understand that the concept of Spark streaming is that the java process should always be running in order for Spark streaming to retrieve new data without submitting the job again.